# why my code doesn't work when I am trying to concatenate a function's return value with a string?

Tags: javascript, function

So, in this code I have a string of 0's and 1's and the length of the string is 32, which will be split in 6 equal parts but the last part will have the length of 2 so I will add (4) 0's after that which will make its length 6. So I wrote a function that will add the remaining 0's which is padding(num).
And that function will be invoked in side the slicing(str) function.
But the code breaks when I try to do execute.
Any help?
Thanks.

```
// This code works.


function padding0s(num) {
  let s = "";
  for (i = 0; i < 6 - num; i++) {
    s += "0";
  }
  return s;
}

function slicing(str) {
  let k = 6;
  let res = [];
  let temp1 = 0;
  let f = padding0s(2);
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; ) {
    res.push(str.slice(i, k));
    i += 6;
    k += 6;
    if (res[temp1].length !== 6) {
      res[temp1] += f;
    }
    temp1++;
  }
  console.log(res);
}

slicing("01000011010011110100010001000101");
```

```
// But this does not..


function padding0s(num) {
  let s = "";
  for (i = 0; i < 6 - num; i++) {
    s += "0";
  }
  return s;
}

function slicing(str) {
  let k = 6;
  let res = [];
  let temp1 = 0;
  
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; ) {
    res.push(str.slice(i, k));
    i += 6;
    k += 6;
    if (res[temp1].length !== 6) {
     let f = padding0s(res[temp1].length);
      res[temp1] += f;
    }
    temp1++;
  }
  console.log(res);
}

slicing("01000011010011110100010001000101");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Always define variables before using them

Not doing so can result in undefined behaviour, which is exactly what is happening in your second case. Here is how:

```
for (i = 0; i < str.length; ) {...}
  // ^ Assignment to undefined variable i
```

In the above for-loop, by using `i` before you define it, you are declaring it as a global variable. But so far, so good, as it doesn't matter, if not for this second problem. The real problem is the call to `padding0s()` in your loop. Let's look at `padding0s`:

```
function padding0s(num) {
  ...
  for (i = 0; i < 6 - num; i++) {
    s += "0";
  }
}
```

This is another loop using `i` without defining it. But since `i` was already defined as a global variable in the parent loop, this loop will be setting its value. So in short, the value of `i` is always equal to `6 - num` in the parent loop. Since your exit condition is `i < str.length`, with a string of length 32 the loop will run forever.

You can get around this in many ways, one of which you've already posted. The other way would be to use `let i` or `var i` instead of `i` in the parent loop. Even better is to write something like this (but beware that [`padEnd` may not work on old browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart#browser_compatibility)):

```js
function slicing(str) {
  return str.match(/.{1,6}/g).map((item) => {
    return item.padEnd(6, "0");
  });
}

console.log(slicing("01000011010011110100010001000101"));
```

Comment: Also, can I use (break) in if condition so after I get the padding, I will exit the entire loop anyway?

Comment: Yes, possible too.